# Can not use `update-source` in bgp neighbor command in Cisco Packet Tracer

Tags: cisco, router, bgp, packet-tracer

In my Cisco Packet Tracer, I have a ISR4321 router:

```
Router1(config-router)#neighbor 12.0.0.2 update-source lo0
                                         ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

I have two questions there:

1) I cannot use `update-source` param in my neighbor command.
2) You see my command `neighbor 12.0.0.2 update-source lo0`, is the `lo0` stands for the Router1's `loopback 0` or the its peer's `loopback 0`?

Comment: `neighbor 12.0.0.2 update-source lo0` is your routers loopback 0 interface.

Comment: You see the command is based on Router1.

Comment: Yes the loopback 0 interface is on Router 1.

Comment: Why I can not use  `update-source` param in my neighbor command?

Comment: Packet Tracer doesn't support update-source on the neighbor command. It's made to only give a basic baseline of how to configure and setup network equipment. You cannot expect every feature to be available, that's also why you would always need a proper testlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) I cannot use update-source param in my neighbor command.

Packet Tracer doesn't support update-source on the neighbor command. It's made to only give a basic baseline of how to configure and setup network equipment. You cannot expect every feature to be available, that's also why you would always need a proper testlab.

> 2) You see my command neighbor 12.0.0.2 update-source lo0, is the lo0
>   stands for the Router1's  loopback 0 or the its peer's loopback 0?

`neighbor 12.0.0.2 update-source lo0` yes, loopback 0 is the interface on Router 1.